# Do i need a payment method for testing in app billing?

Tags: android, testing, in-app-billing

I am trying to test In app billing (Version 3) for android with my own product IDs. I have uploaded a concept to the play store, added my gmail account for licence testing and installed the same app version on my device.

When i try to test my the in app billing, its asking me for a payment method. Is this normal? Or did forgot something to test the IAB?

**edit**
The static products works fine. But how can i test my own product IDs

Comment: Yes, you need to add a credit card to your account if you are testing with real products. If you are using `android.test.purchased` as your test product you don't need a payment method.

Comment: @Luizje take a look at http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: oki, thnx i will try it out with the test product

Comment: Everything works fine with the static products. Now back to the real problem. How can i test my own product IDs like these http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html

Comment: @Luizje You won't be able to test if you're using the same email account as your developer ID on the device. You'll have to factory reset and add another one.

Comment: oke, but i'm not using the same email account as the email that is registered as a developers account